# Files.walk identify if file is from subfolder or mainfolder

Tags: java, filter, stream

I finally got my Files.walk working now my question is if there is any way to identify if the file collected to the list comes from a subfolder or mainfolder because there is a delete function for these files but the files from the sub folder the user should not be able to delete.

```
 private static List<FileInfo> listBackupFilesInLocalDir(String localPath, Predicate<String> fileNamePredicate) {
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(localPath))) {
        return files.filter(p -> fileNamePredicate.test(p.getFileName().toString()))
                    .map(p -> new FileInfo(p.getFileName().toString(), p.toFile().length()))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error listing directories", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This is the function which find and collects all the files. Is it some sort of filter I need or is it even possible to do what I want?

```
  deleteLocalFile.addClickListener(event -> {
        try {
            Files.delete(Paths.get(this.localStorage, String.valueOf(localFilesComboBox.getValue())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            UI.getCurrent().access(() -> Notification.show(e.getMessage(), Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE));
        }

        UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
            localFilesComboBox.removeAllItems();
            localFilesComboBox.addItems(listBackupFiles());
        });
    });
```

The above is the delete method and what I want to is simply like a

```
if(from folder a) {
deny delete
}
```

or something similar

Comment: Do you want to do this before or after the function returns? Because a simple solution is to reiterate the the `List<FileInfo>` and see if the file is in folder `a` or `b`

Comment: It really doesnt matter if its before or after aslong as i can check in my delete file method if the file is from folder a or b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you want to be able to only delete files, and only files, in the main folder, and not files in the sub folders. Thus you need a list of files in the main folder. You can do this by checking the URL of the `FileInfo` objects from the result of your `listBackupFilesInLocalDir` method. This can be done in the following manner:

```
public ArrayList<FileInfo> filesInMainFolder(string mainPath,
                                         ArrayList<FileInfo> files) {
    ArrayList<FileInfo> res = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();

    for (FileInfo info : files) {
        String url = info.getUrl().toString();
        // Get the path of the File for which we have file information
        url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));

        // Is file in the main folder
        if (url.compareTo(mainPath) == 0 && info.isDirectory() == false) {

            res.add(info);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The method should be fairly easy to follow. And option I have not include here is the [`getUrl()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()) method on URLs because I am not 100% certain how it works. If it gets you the directory path, use that instead and drop the conversion to string of the url and simply use `info.getUrl().getPath()`

Answer (score 0):

To know at which depth you are relative to `localPath`, you could count the number of elements in the path. Something like this:

```
int mainFolderDepth = Paths.get(localPath).toRealPath().getNameCount();

//in your stream
int folderDepth = p.toRealPath().getNameCount();
if (! Files.isDirectory(p)) folderDepth--; //don't count the file name
if (folderDepth != mainFolderDepth) { /* not in main folder */ }
```

Alternatively, in your file walk, make sure you don't enter subfolders if you want to ignore them by setting the `maxDepth` argument to 1.